# accurate image aspect ratio in python

Tags: python, image-processing, floating-accuracy, aspect-ratio

I have the following code to get the aspect ratio of an image

```
img0 = color.rgb2gray(io.imread("C:\\work\\TRAIN\\SET1\\bus.jpg"))
img0 = resize(img0, (40, 116))
ar = 1.0 * (img0.shape[1]/img0.shape[0])
print "aspect ratio: " 
print ar
```

The output is `2.0`. But that's not true. 
For an image with width 116 and height 40, the aspect ratio should be `116/40 = 2.9`.

Where is my calculation going wrong?

Comment: `116/40` will do [floor division](http://python-history.blogspot.ch/2010/08/why-pythons-integer-division-floors.html) (round down to the next integer) on Python 2.7. Use something like `float(img0.shape[1]) / img0.shape[0]` to get floating point division.

Comment: That worked! If you add that as an answer I'll select it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`116/40` will do [floor division](http://python-history.blogspot.ch/2010/08/why-pythons-integer-division-floors.html) (round down to the next integer) on Python 2.x.

Use something like `float(img0.shape[1]) / img0.shape[0]` to get floating point division (which is the default behavior for the `/` operator on Python 3.x).

The best option is probably to use `from __future__ import division` (as the *very first* import in your script) - this will ensure your script will use floating point division both on Python 2.x and Python 3.x.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in you case is that img0.shape[1] and img0.shape[0] are both integers. You have performed integer division, and then converted it to float. You could try:

```
float(img0.shape[1]) / img0.shape[0]
```

or

```
1.0 * img0.shape[1] / img0.shape[0]
```

or, my recommended method, is to add as the first line of code in the file this import

```
from __future__ import division
```

This will make "/" always perform floating point calculation, to avoid such cases. If you want to specifically use integer division, use "//", as in 10 // 3